# used mv file.sql /folder instead of mv file.sql folder/

Tags: copy, mv

Hello I made the mistake of using `mv file.sql /destinationfolder` instead of  `mv file.sql destinationfolder/`- using su root. Now I can't find my sql file. is there a way to find it/recover it?

Comment: You should modify your question specifying that `/destinationfolder` already existed and it contains files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the file to be /destinationfilder so all you need to do is rename it back

```
sudo mv /destinationfolder /some/path/destinationfolder/file.sql
```

e.g.

```
touch file.sql
sudo mv file.sql /destinationfolder
ls -l /destinationfolder
-rw-rw-r--. 1 iain iain 0 Oct 13 16:52 /destinationfolder

sudo mv /destinationfolder /home/iain/destinationfolder/file.sql
ls -l /home/iain/destinationfolder/file.sql
-rw-rw-r--. 1 iain iain 0 Oct 13 16:52 file.sql
```

Comment: there is already an existing folder with the name destinationfolder and it has files on it.what would happen if i mv back ?

Comment: thanks great!! I almost lost my breath all october data is on that file

Comment: @stacknoob: Then why don't you have a backup if this might be the result?

Answer (score 1):

Your `./file.sql` has become `/destinationfolder` (this is not a folder but a file).
If you do `ls /` you should see your file. If you do `cat /destinationfolder` you should see content of your file.

With `su` privilege move the file back:
`mv /destinationfolder destinationfolder/file.sql`

### EDIT

I see you added some comments specifying that `/destinationfolder` already existed and contained files. That means your file has been moved into this folder; so if you do `ls /destinationfolder` you should see your file there. You might need `su` permissions do access that folder.

Again, with `su` privileges move the file back:
`mv /destinationfolder/file.sql destinationfolder/file.sql`

### Note

`/destinationfolder` is a folder part of your root directory `/`
`destinationfolder/` is a folder part of your current working directory `/current_working_directory/destinationfolder`